# Add user input to a li element

Tags: javascript, html, list, user-input

**EDITED**

I am currently trying to figure out my homework (no, I don't want someone to just do it for me) and I am stuck. I have a simple website where a user types something into a text box and when they click the submit button, the input should show up in a list.

My textbook is asking me to make the function processInput() that takes user input and puts it into the list. My problem is were it asks me to "Set the content of the element with an *id* equal to the *listItem* to the value of the element with the *id* of *inputbox*." I thought it would be this

```
document.getElementById("listItem").innerHTML = document.getElementById("inputBox");
```

But I get an error on this line saying: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

**EDIT:** Thank you all for the help. I have removed the quotations around listItem and fixed a [object HTMLInputElement] issue, now it works.

The EDITED chunk of code:

```
      <div id="results">
      <ul>
         <li id="item1"></li> 
         <li id="item2"></li>
         <li id="item3"></li>
         <li id="item4"></li>
         <li id="item5"></li>
      </ul>
      <p id="resultsExpl"></p>
  </div>
  <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="inputBox" id="placeLabel">
          Type here, then click Submit:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="inputBox" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <button type="button" id="button">Submit</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
</article>

<script>
    // Global variables
    var i = 1;
    var listItem = "";

    // function to process input
    function processInput()
    {
        if(i <= 5)
        {
            listItem = "item" + i;
            document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
            document.getElementById("inputBox").value = "";
            if (i === 5)
            {
                document.getElementById("resultsExpl").innerHTML = "Thanks for your suggestions.";
            }
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    // Backward compatable event listener for submit button
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
    if(submitButton.addEventListener)
    {
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", processInput, false);
    }
    else if(submit.attachEvent)
    {
        submit.attachEvent("onclick", processInput);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I stopped reading, because there is no element with id listItem. Is your code complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is simple -- you're supplying a string `"listItem"` to `getElementById`, but the ID `listItem` doesn't exist.

What you want to do is supply your variable you're already declaring:

```
listItem = "item" + i;
```

As this will look like `"item6"`, etc.

All that means for your function is -- take of the quotes, so you're using the variable instead of a string:

```
document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove quotes from listItem because you declared listItem as variable.

```
document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = document.getElementById("inputBox");
```

Comment: Good catch! I think many of us though it was the usual "element not found" issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need an element listItem. Thats why you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an element in your HTML with an id of "listItem" so

```
document.getElementById("listItem")
```

is null

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
document.getElementById("listItem").innerHTML = document.getElementById("inputBox");
```

You are literally searching for an element that has the id `"listItem"` (you're searching for a STRING!)

But you set the variable `listItem` above, so use that instead:

```
document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = document.getElementById("inputBox");
```

Once you get that working, you'll notice that you're setting the content (`innerHTML`) of the list item to the ACTUAL ELEMENT (that's what `getElementById()` is spitting out). That's not really possible, so a smart browser will tell you what that object is... as a string: `[object HTMLInputElement]`. Your instructions tell you to set the list item content to the VALUE of that input, not the input itself.